# Is it possible to customize the Debug/Trace.Assert dialog box?

Tags: .net, vb.net, assert, assertions, assertion

In my code, I often use `Trace.Assert()` to verify various conditions are true. This causes a dialog to display if a condition is false, such as this one:
[image: Assertion failure dialogue example]

This dialogue is not very user-friendly, so I'd like to replace it with a good-looking UI that hides technical details by default, unless the user asks for them.

Is anyone aware of a way to specify a default custom dialogue when using `Trace.Assert()`, to be used in place of this one?

Comment: User friendly???   Your user won't see any asserts, they are removed in the Release build.  It was meant for you to fix your bugs.

Comment: Right...that's the case with Debug.Assert, but not with Trace.Assert - Trace.Assert keeps the dialogs in production if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may come a little late for you, but you could try implementing your own Dialog and register it as Debug or Trace Listener.

Look at this page to see an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4423/Assert-Enhancements

If you already solved the problem from you original post, let us know how.
Thanks, Sascha

Comment: Great, this is just what I was looking for. I'd put this task on the back-burner, but now I might go back and implement something like this.

Comment: Just a word of caution: I just tried the approach described in the link I posted. I works in most of the cases. It only fails, if your Debug.Assert (or probably Trace) is called in a background thread. There are several places where for example the assertion dialogs Text-property is set from a method that is invoked by the background thread, while the dialog was probably created on the UI-thread. That hangs your application. Make sure changes to dialog are made e.g. in the Shown-Event. Also you might need to use Invoke on an existing form to show the dialog.